# Maximize child window of other application (VB .Net)I'

Tags: .net, winapi, api, maximize

I'v used findwindowex to find the child window. I used findwindow to find the big application, and I found that with spy++. I know that it is the right one because I'm able to sendkeys to it and they work. I'm trying to maximize it but it does not work. I tried to do the showwindow call and use the 3 costant to maximize it, with no luck. What could be going wrong? Does anyone have examples on maximizing a childwindow?

Thanks

*I'm dealing with an mdi child window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, child windows can't be maximized or minimized. The only exception I can think of is MDI child windows. Is that what you're dealing with here?

Comment: Spy++ sayis it is part of an mdi client... in the program it has minimize, maximize, etc but i cant just tell the program to click on those :-p, how would you do it with mdi? thanks